# How to redirect user back to the previous page using passport-spotify

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, spotify

I am using passport-spotify - https://github.com/jmperez/passport-spotify for authentication in my web app and I am unable to redirect the user back to the previous page.

I have looked into https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-ensure-login which talks about storing the req.url in req.session.returnTo for later use. But this isn't working b/c by the time I receive the "/callback" from spotify, req.session.returnTo is undefined.

Would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: what happens if you use `successReturnToOrRedirect` option during authenticating?

Comment: @hassansin - Thanks. That works. But how do I know If the redirect was due to a failure or success then?

Comment: It doesn't use the above parameter on failures. For failures you can use another parameter `failureRedirect`

Comment: @hassasin - what if I use both like this `passport.authenticate('spotify', { successReturnToOrRedirect: "/", failureRedirect: '/' })`

Comment: You can use both, see my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Passport takes few parameters for handling redirection:

- `successRedirect`:  After successful login, user will redirect to given URL
- `successReturnToOrRedirect`: After successful login, if `req.session.returnTo` exists, then the user will be redirected to
  `req.session.returnTo` else to the given URL
- `failureRedirect`:  After failed login, user will redirect to given URL

So use it like this:

```
passport.authenticate('spotify', { 
 failureRedirect: '/login',
 successReturnToOrRedirect: '/profile'
})
```